# jsPDF not printing as it is

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

[my HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMQfg.jpg)

[my PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klUBN.jpg)

I want to print the details on HTML page exactly on PDF.
I am using jsPDF to print the details onto the PDF.
Here is my code:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
var source = $('#mymy')[0];
var specialElementHandlers = {
// element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
'#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
    // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
    return true
  }
}

var margins = {
   top: 80,
   bottom: 60,
   left: 40,
   width: 522
};


pdf.fromHTML(source, margins.left, margins.top, {
    'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
    , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
},
function (dispose) {
  // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
  //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
  pdf.save('Test.pdf');
},
margins
)
```

Html code:

```
 <div class="form-group" id="mymy">
                <ul ng-repeat="sec in abc" class="media-list tab-pane fade in active" style="border-style: solid;">

                    <ul ng-repeat="k in sec.usertype" ng-if="secs(k._id)">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">{{k.sec_name}}</div> 
                            <div class="panel-body">

                            <ul ng-repeat="l in k.keywords">                           

                            <div class="row" name="options" id="{{k._id}}" ng-if="check(l._id)">
                           <div class="col-sm-5"> <img src="/client/app/images/t.png" width="20" height="15"><b>{{l.keyword}}</b></div>
                             <div class="col-sm-5"> <p>{{l.description}}</p></div>                                                              
                            </div>                            

                        </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </ul>                       

                </ul>       
                </div>
```

I want exact page to be printed on PDF.
I am not familiar with jsPDF.

Comment: What the problem you facing currently with your script? please write in brief

Comment: i want the same format visible in html page on my PDF

Comment: Yes but when you run your script, what happen currently? isn't it showing design in same way OR its not printing at all OR any other JS error you are getting?

Comment: Have you tried including CSS inside your div/ inline css?

Comment: @Rupal Check images that OP provided.

Comment: @Rupal please see both the images included in start

Comment: @Justinas how can we include CSS? jspDF doesn't took it automatically?

Comment: By using `<style>` tag...

Comment: lemme check inline styles

Comment: @Justinas not working

Comment: @AvinashSharma can you attach HTML template content from which you are creating PDF

Comment: @Rupal done...attached

Comment: @AvinashSharma Have you solved this ? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @Dalvik I am able to print screenshot of it and a self made details in pdf. These two solutions worked for me... but the solution to above asked question didn't got yet.

Comment: @Avinash Sharma how did you print a screenshot of it?

Comment: Hi @strypeez you can't print a screenshot... you all need to build on your own, by specifying exact x-y coordinates. You can get help from here: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF. Still you find any difficulties, you can reach me :)

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old one but ng-if is breaking up the Dom therefore you'll have to build the pdf in your script instead of using pdf.fromHtml e.g. the dom elements.